# Scapy packets creation and the principles used behind

Tags: python, networking, protocols, scapy

I am actually working on a network sniffing tool in python by using scapy. I am not an expert in Network but i had some lectures about it so it's not completely new for me. My problem is that I don't understand some notions applied on Scapy like the stacking of layers. They don't provide technical docs for their library like doc.python.org.  For example, the official website gives this example of utilisation :

> > > IP()/TCP()
> > > <IP frag=0 proto=TCP |<TCP |>>

First: why do we stack layers to use TCP ? I thought that TCP automaticaly used the IP protocol to communicate with servers/other machines so normally we don't have to specify an IP layer no ?

Second: the website said that we have a upper and lower layer so which one is the upper/lower in this example ? Also same what is the order of layer in this ex : Ether()/IP()/IP()/UDP().  Also i don't understand the scheme they provide to try to explain it (here : https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) like what is the Fields overloaded by upper layer and what is the consequence in the packet.

Third: in which conditions do we use stacking layers and what kind of applications is it used for ? Can we stack infinite numbers of layers/protocols and how would the decapsulation of the packet be done ?

Sorry for the bunch of questions and if someone could answer me it would be really great.

I tried some examples in books like Black Hat Python. The examples are working but they don't provide good explanations.